# create copy of branch minus changes to certain subdir with git

Tags: git

I have been working on a branch in git, and have concluded that all of the changes to a certain subdirectory need to be scrapped. Those changes have been spread over many commits, and mixed with other changes that need to be kept. There are a lot of commits, so I would prefer to not have to specify which parts of each commit to keep manually.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want to discard all changes made in the subdirectory after the commit `abcd`.
You can do that by the following commands:

```
rm -rf path/to/the/subdirectory
git checkout abcd path/to/the/subdirectory
git add path/to/the/subdirectory
git commit
```

This way adds a commit. Is this what you want?

Comment: I was hoping to have the changes not show up at all (via `git log` etc.) but I'll take it. Thanks!